# Decidable membership for subgroup generated by three elements in $F_2\times F_2$

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic

Let $F_2$ be the non-abelian free group on two generators. Let $G\subset F_2\times F_2$ be a subgroup generated by three elements. Is there an algorithm deciding if a given element of $F_2\times F_2$ lies in $G$?

Comment: Why three in particular?

Comment: @DerekHolt because the number of generators for Mihailova subgroup is 2+the number of relations in a group with undecidable word problem and groups with one relation all have decidable word problems (and it is not known if groups with two relations have decidable word problems).

Comment: Thanks! But you should really provide context like that when asking the question.

Comment: This could be true. By Goursat's lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma), "the subdirect product of two groups can be described as a fiber product and vice versa". It may be that one can use this to reduce the problem you describe to the word problem in one-relator groups.

Comment: As an example: What is the subgroup generated by $(a^3, b^2), (b^3, a^3), (b^2a^2, aba)$? I have no idea how to think about this.

Comment: @MattF.: your subgroup is free of rank $3$, freely generated by the above elements. This is because its projection to the first factor is free of rank $3$ (which can be easily checked, as it's a subgroup of the free group $F(a,b)$, generated by $a^3,b^3,b^2a^2$). This also shows that the subgroup has trivial intersection with the second factor. A symetric argument shows the same for the second factor.